# How to recursively add unknown primitive elements?

Tags: javascript, json, properties

I want to be able to recursively add elements to a single object, and can't use the `salutations[element]` syntax as the `value` of each `key` will be determined by user input, so I need to primitively use `salutations` to set each object of `greetings`.

```
greetings = { key: value, chain: {} }
salutations = greetings.chain
for(var i = 0; i < j; i++){
    salutations = { key: value, chain: {} }
    salutations = salutations.chain
}
```

I want the result on the first iteration to be `greetings.chain = { key: value, chain: {} }`, and the second iteration to be `greetings.chain.chain = { key: value, chain: {} }`, and so forth.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost works. The parameters of the for loop are a little mixed up and you want to set the new `chain` before you reassign salutation in the loop:

```js
let greeting = { key: 'value', chain: {} }
let salutations = greeting
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
   salutations.chain = { key: 'value', chain: {} }
   salutations = salutations.chain
}

console.log(greeting)
console.log(greeting.chain.chain.chain.chain)
```

Comment: Grrr! You beat me too it. Stupid Captcha slowed me down haha.